# Warning When Trying To Compile Haskell Programs In OS X 10.9

Tags: c, haskell, gcc, compiler-warnings

When i am trying to compile (cabal install as well) in haskell i am getting this warning

```
/var/folders/hc/mp6156cx05v9l1x78qf4b_gh0000gn/T/11272.c:1:12:
 warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
int foo() {}
           ^
1 warning generated.
```

- Every time i recompile the number (11272) in the end changes.

I wonder where it come form and how can i stop it.

I have OS X mavericks 10.9 and i recently installed [GHC on XCode5 Clang Patch](http://justtesting.org/post/64947952690/the-glasgow-haskell-compiler-ghc-on-os-x-10-9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling haskell-platform solve the problem.

```
 brew rm ghc

 brew unlink haskell-platform

 brew install haskell-platform
```